# Area of rectangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that why we take area of a rectangle proportional to the product of its width and height. I also know why take area proportional to product. It is due to the theorem of Joint Variation. But it's really hard for me to make a visual concept or make sense of that how product of width and height give us the area of a rectangle?

Comment: With regard to the area of the rectangle height into width formula is derived by simple integration

Comment: That is completely circular, @Heisenberg. You defined the (Riemann) integral as the sum of the areas of smaller rectangles in the first place.

Comment: Area is a very tricky business. More sophisticated approaches to area, e.g., Riemann and Lebesgue integrals, both require the axiom that the area of a rectangle is the product of its sides. You absolutely can't rely on any of these methods to *prove* the formula for area of a rectangle.

Comment: Possibly [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800699).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area of a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ is *defined* to be $ab$. The motivation for this definition is coming from counting points in discrete rectangles. If you arrange $b$ rows of marbles, each row having $a$ marbles, then the total number of marbles you have in the rectangle is $ab$.